# how to implement dynamic Query in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to implement a single query and a dynamic query.
there are 4 tables through which i m filtering the tables using group by clause.
but now i want to combine these four tables and make a dynamic query.
On Selecting the Values t will be  Like below eg 
eg :

```
NSString *strQuery = @"Select * from TableName where "
```

**step :1 :**

entity1 query will be :

```
Select * from TableName where entity1 = 'S'
```

**step :2**

entity 2 query will be :

```
Select * from TableName where entity1 = 'S' AND entity 2 = '100S'
```

**step :3**

entity 3 query will be :

```
Select * from TableName where entity1 = 'S' AND entity 2 = '100S' AND entity3 = 'Fly'
```

Comment: what is entity1,2 and 3 means ?

Comment: i have to append the string when the value from table is selected and then the dynamic query executes. do u remember of probability.

Comment: can u give me ur mail id

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. It's best if column names didn't have spaces in them. If you have spaces, you need to put the column name in quotes, e.g.

   ```
   Select * from TableName where entity1 = 'S' AND 'entity 2' = '100S'
   ```

   It's best to bypass this issue altogether, by making sure your column names don't have spaces in them, e.g. `entity2` rather than `entity 2`.
2. Rather than using `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL, it's safer to use `?` placeholders in your SQL and then use [`sqlite3_bind_text()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to set the values. This way, if the variables have any characters that might mess up a manually created SQL statement (e.g. the field has a single quote character, `'`), it bypasses that issue. So, you might have:

   ```
   sqlite3 *database;
   if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s open error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

   NSString *sql = @"Select * from TableName where entity1 = ? AND entity2 = ?";
   NSString *entity1 = @"S";
   NSString *entity2 = @"100S";

   sqlite3_stmt *statement;

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s prepare SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [entity1 UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s bind entity 1 error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

   if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [entity2 UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog(@"%s bind entity 2 error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

   int rc;

   while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
   {
       // do whatever you want with the results

       const unsigned char *entity1 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
       const unsigned char *entity2 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
       const unsigned char *entity3 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

       NSLog(@"%s %s %s", entity1, entity2, entity3);
   }

   if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
       NSLog(@"%s step SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   sqlite3_close(database);
   ```

   Admittedly, this use of `sqlite_bind_text` is a little more cumbersome, but it's more robust. The use of this convention is important if you can't be entirely sure if the fields you're looking for might have the single quote character. It's critical if you're building your SQL based upon some search criteria provided by the user (e.g. find "Joe's Bar and Grill", where the apostrophe in "Joe's" can cause you a little heartache if you don't use `sqlite3_bind_text` or otherwise code around this issue). While this is less of an issue for an app than a web site, you simply don't want your app susceptible to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
3. The above `sqlite_bind_text` syntax is greatly simplified if you use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a wonderful little Objective-C wrapper for SQLite:

   ```
   FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
   NSAssert(database, @"unable to open database");

   if (![database open])
       NSLog(@"%@", [self.database lastErrorMessage]);

   FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"Select * from TableName where entity1 = ? AND entity2 = ?", @"S", @"100S"];
   NSAssert(rs, [self.database lastErrorMessage]);

   while ([rs next])
   {
       NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", rs[0], rs[1], rs[2]);
   }

   [rs close];
   [database close];
   ```

   This enjoys the benefits of `sqlite_bind_text`, without dragging you through the weeds of the `sqlite` function calls.

---

If you wanted to have a function that you could call with a variable number of parameters, you could do it in a bunch of different ways, building your SQL dynamically. I'll provide an example below with a disclaimer that I really don't like building SQL manually as the code ends up suffering from readability problems. I'd rather sacrifice parsimonious code with something more legible, but I'm inferring from your question that you're wondering how you could build your SQL dynamically, so I'll provide a sample, with the above caveat. I'll also say that there are a ton of ways of tackling this, and this is only one such example.

Anyway, let's assume that you want to use a dictionary as the parameter of which columns had which values, you could invoke it as follows. If you only had entity 1, you'd call that like so:

```
[self selectTableWithDictionary:@{@"entity1":@"S"}];
```

Or if you had both entity 1 and entity 2, you'd call it like so:

```
[self selectTableWithDictionary:@{@"entity1":@"S", @"entity2":@"100S"}];
```

The method to then parse this dictionary, manually build the SQL, and then bind the individual columns might look like:

```
- (void)selectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *fieldNames = [dictionary allKeys];
    NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];

    // build the sql

    NSMutableString *sql = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Select * from TableName"];
    if ([fieldNames count]){
        [sql appendString:@" where "];
        [sql appendString:[fieldNames componentsJoinedByString:@" = ? AND "]];
        [sql appendString:@" = ?"];
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    // prepare the sql

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s prepare SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

    // bind the values

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [fieldNames count]; i++)
        if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, i+1, [values[i] UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSLog(@"%s bind column # %d error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, i+1, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    int rc;

    // iterate through the results

    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        const unsigned char *entity1 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        const unsigned char *entity2 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        const unsigned char *entity3 = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

        NSLog(@"%s %s %s", entity1, entity2, entity3);
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"%s step SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

The FMDB implementation might look like:

```
- (void)selectTableWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *fieldNames = [dictionary allKeys];
    NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];

    // build the sql

    NSMutableString *sql = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Select * from TableName"];
    if ([fieldNames count]){
        [sql appendString:@" where "];
        [sql appendString:[fieldNames componentsJoinedByString:@" = ? AND "]];
        [sql appendString:@" = ?"];
    }

    // execute the sql

    FMResultSet *rs = [self.database executeQuery:sql
                             withArgumentsInArray:values];
    NSAssert(rs, [self.database lastErrorMessage]);

    // iterate through the results

    while ([rs next])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", rs[0], rs[1], rs[2]);
    }

    [rs close];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "stringWithFormat" method of NSString like,

```
NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from TableName where entity1 = '%@' AND entity 2 = '%@'",@"S",@"100S"];
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For static value You can try

```
NSString *strQuery =@"Select * from TableName where entity1 = 'S' AND entity 2 = '100S'";
```

for dynamic value you can try

```
NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from TableName where entity1 = '%@' AND entity 2 = '%@'",entity1_obj,entity2_obj];
```